# How to install wheel package of tensorRT for tensorflow on Windows 10?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, tensorrt

From NVIDIA tensorRT documentation I have completed the first 4 steps for zip file for windows.But Now I can't really understand the 5th and 6th step specially where I have to 3 things to get it work for **"tensorFlow"**. I can't understand how to execute this line

*python3 -m pip install <installpath>\graphsurgeon\graphsurgeon-0.4.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl*

Here is the link: https://docs.nvidia.com/deeplearning/tensorrt/install-guide/index.html#installing-zip

P.S:I am very new to this world of machine learning and TensorFlow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to open a terminal with a python environment.

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd> and type `cmd`+<kbd>Enter</kbd> to open a terminal. You can check if you have the correct Python version by running `python --version`.

More information about package installing can be found here:
https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/installing-packages/#requirements-for-installing-packages

For install command execution, replace `<installpath>` by the location, where you installed TensorRT, e.g., if you installed it in `C:\Program Files\TensorRT` use:
`python3 -m pip install "C:\Program Files"\TensorRT\graphsurgeon\graphsurgeon-0.4.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl`

This is described in 2) from your link:

> Choose where you want to install TensorRT. The zip file will install
> everything into a subdirectory called TensorRT-7.x.x.x. This new
> subdirectory will be referred to as `<installpath>` in the steps below.

Comment: But how do you write  /<installpath>. This thing baffles me alot.

Comment: That clears a lot. Can you please describe what they want me to do at step 3 where it has 3  sub-steps (a,b,c)

Comment: Can you please tell me how do I prepare the python environment before installing?

Comment: If my answer, helps your for this part, please remember to accept it. For new questions, please start a new question!

Comment: But, there are plenty of answers to the pythin environment question already answered on SO. Just copy the question to the search function ;-)

Comment: I was too busy to figure out the whole thing that's why I missed your comments.Sorry for the delay.Living in village makes things more unresponsive.As I have found stackOverflow is a place where people get annoyed by asking questions like.But math -stack is far more generous like you.Computers are like magic wand in my place.So please forgive any dumb questions.

Comment: Just to clarify, your question is suitable for SO. There's no need to apologize. The reason for opening a new question is really just, that this is supposed to also help other people that have a similar problem as well. Therefore, questions are supposed to be specific and not change after you've found an answer.